# select specific patterns from string to create resources - terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I will like to create resources on AWS using patterns from a variable in terraform.

For example:

```
proyects = ["proyect1/X", "proyect1/Y", "proyect2/X", ...]

resource "aws_example" "proyect1" {
count = length(var.proyects) <-- only using the proyect1/... ones
name = var.proyects[count.index] <-- only using the proyect1/... ones
```

resource proyect1/X created

resource proyect1/Y created

```
resource "aws_example" "proyect2" {
count = length(var.proyects) <-- only using the proyect2/... ones
name = var.proyects[count.index] <-- only using the proyect2/... ones
```

resource proyect2/X created

resource proyect2/Y created

---

I don't know if this is possible...I'm trying using https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by `proyect1` and `proyect2` and use `for_each`:

```
variable "proyects" {
  default = ["proyect1/X", "proyect1/Y", "proyect2/X", "proyect2/Y", "proyect2/Z"]
}


resource "aws_example" "proyect1" {
  for_each = [for v in var.proyects : v if length(regexall("proyect1.*", v)) > 0]
  name = each.key
}

resource "aws_example" "proyect2" {
  for_each = [for v in var.proyects : v if length(regexall("proyect2.*", v)) > 0]
  name = each.key
}
```